# Why do some characters are not displaying correctly in this website?

Tags: high-sierra, font, websites, unicode

If I go to this website: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_misc_symbols.asp I can see some of the first glyphs, but later down the page most are missing.

In their place, I can only see the "missing character" glyph, which looks like an empty block.

What does this happen? Am I missing some font? Should I install some extra font in my Mac OS?

Is this the expected behavior of my OS, or is it a bug?

By the way, the above website's glyphs render just fine in any other OS I've tried (both Linux and Windows).

Browser: Latest Chrome
OS version: High Sierra 10.13.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You presumably need to download and add a font.  Try [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/).

If you have an iOS device, I think you should find the same behavior.  Apple's supplied fonts do not cover all of Unicode, which has well over 100,000 characters.

To check whether your MacOS has a font covering a specific character, you can open Character Viewer (Edit > Emoji and Symbols), select Unicode, and find the hex number.

Comment: Hey Tom, thanks for the answer although I find it really weird that macOS by default covers only the absolutely basic ones while it is being developed by a company like Apple. And there are free open source fonts that can be used as fallbacks.